# my rating and comment section is not responsive and showing horrible on small screens

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass

i am new on sass and css , i wanted to create a rating and comment bar and on laptop computer it is looking fine but when i make it on small screens , it seems that probably the latout is wrong or maybe i did not respect something in grid layout perhaps or maybe the scss properties are wrong

Here what i have tried:

```
   <div class="container-fluid rate__box" >
<div class="row mt-3 mb-3">
  <div class="col col-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-3 img__gold "> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/xELPaag.jpg" width="80" class="rounded-circle mt-2"> </div>
          <div class="col-9">
              <div class="comment-box">
                  <h4>Add a comment</h4>
                  <div class="rating"> <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5" id="5"><label for="5">☆</label> <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4" id="4"><label for="4">☆</label> <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3" id="3"><label for="3">☆</label> <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" id="2"><label for="2">☆</label> <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" id="1"><label for="1">☆</label> </div>
                  <div class="comment-area"> <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="what is your view?" rows="4"></textarea> </div>
                  <div class="comment-btns mt-2 text-center">
               <button class="btn btn-success btn__hover send btn-sm">Send <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right ml-1"></i></button> 
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
    
   </div>
```

scss:

```
.rate__box {

.col-12 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #e04529;
    padding-top: 3rem;
    padding-bottom: 3rem;
    
    .card {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        min-width: 0;
        padding: 1.25rem;
        width: 28.125rem;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        background-color: #fff;
        background-clip: border-box;
        border-radius: 0.375rem;
    }
}

.img__gold{
    width: 5rem;
}
    
    .comment-box {
        padding: 0.3125rem;
        margin-left: 2px;
    }
    
    .comment-area textarea {
        resize: none;
        border: 1px solid #ad9f9f
    }
    
    .form-control:focus {
        color: #495057;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-color:  #284876;
        outline: 0;
    }
    
    .btn-success {
     height: 2rem;
    }

    .send {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #ff0000;
        border-color: #ff0000
    }
    
    .send:hover {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #f50202;
        border-color: #f50202
    }
    
    .rating {
        display: flex;
        margin-top: -0.625rem;
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
        margin-left: -0.25rem;
        float: left
    }
    
    .rating>input {
        display: none
    }
    
    .rating>label {
        position: relative;
        width: 1.1875rem;
        font-size: 1.5625rem;
        color: #ff0000;
        cursor: pointer
    }
    
    .rating>label::before {
        content: "\2605";
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0
    }
    
    .rating>label:hover:before,
    .rating>label:hover~label:before {
        opacity: 1 !important
    }
    
    .rating>input:checked~label:before {
        opacity: 1
    }
    
    .rating:hover>input:checked~label:before {
        opacity: 0.4
    }

}

.btn{
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: transform 400ms; //pour indiquer au navigateur que la proprietés de transition est tranform
    &__hover:hover {
        transform: scale(1.15);
    }

    &--start:hover{
        transform: scale(1.05);
    }
}



@media screen and (max-width:900px){
    .carousel-inner > .carousel-item > img,
    .carousel-inner > .carousel-item > a > img {
        display: block;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: 18rem !important;
    } 
}

@media screen and (max-width:500px){
    .rate__box {

        .col-12 {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            background: #e04529;
            padding-top: 3rem;
            padding-bottom: 3rem;
            
            .card {
                position: relative;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                min-width: 0;
                padding: 1.25rem;
                width: 28.125rem;
                word-wrap: break-word;
                background-color: #fff;
                background-clip: border-box;
                border-radius: 0.375rem;
            }
        }
        
          
            
            .comment-box {
                padding: 0.3125rem;
                margin-left: 4px;
            }
            
            .comment-area textarea {
                resize: none;
                border: 1px solid #ad9f9f
            }
            
            .form-control:focus {
                color: #495057;
                background-color: #fff;
                border-color:  #284876;
                outline: 0;
            }
            
            .btn-success {
             height: 2rem;
            }
        
            .send {
                color: #fff;
                background-color: #ff0000;
                border-color: #ff0000
            }
            
            .send:hover {
                color: #fff;
                background-color: #f50202;
                border-color: #f50202
            }
            
            .rating {
                display: flex;
                margin-top: -0.625rem;
                flex-direction: row-reverse;
                margin-left: -0.25rem;
                float: left
            }
            
            .rating>input {
                display: none
            }
            
            .rating>label {
                position: relative;
                width: 1.1875rem;
                font-size: 1.5625rem;
                color: #ff0000;
                cursor: pointer
            }
            
            .rating>label::before {
                content: "\2605";
                position: absolute;
                opacity: 0
            }
            
            .rating>label:hover:before,
            .rating>label:hover~label:before {
                opacity: 1 !important
            }
            
            .rating>input:checked~label:before {
                opacity: 1
            }
            
            .rating:hover>input:checked~label:before {
                opacity: 0.4
            }

            .img__gold{
                width: 4.375rem;
            }
        
        }
}
```

Here a screen capture:

large screen:

[image]

small screen:

[image]

full scss file:

```
@import "variable_overrides";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";



.col__animation{  
    display: flex;
    border-radius: 1rem !important;
    border: 1px solid #284876;
    height: 60px !important;
    align-items: center;
     
    #object {
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        background: blueviolet;
        margin-top: 2px;
        margin-bottom: 1px;
        margin-right: 3px;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: transform 1000ms;
        transition-timing-function: linear;
    }
    
    &:hover{
        #object{
            transition: transform 1000ms;
            transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
            transform: translateX(100px);
        }
    }

}

.form{

    &-control--rounded:hover {
        border: 1px solid #284876;
        box-shadow: none;
    }

    &-control__text{
        border-radius: 100rem !important;
    }
    &-control__text--area{
        border-radius: 1rem !important;
    }
    &-control:focus{
        border: 1px solid #284876;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
    &-control:not(:focus):invalid{
        border: 1px solid #dc3545;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
    &-control-underlined {
        border-width: 0;
        border-bottom-width: 1px;
        border-radius: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
      }
    
      &-control::placeholder {
        font-size: 0.95rem;
        color: #aaa;
        font-style: italic;
      }
}

  
.rate__box {

.col-12 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #e04529;
    padding-top: 3rem;
    padding-bottom: 3rem;
    
    .card {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        min-width: 0;
        padding: 1.25rem;
        width: 28.125rem;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        background-color: #fff;
        background-clip: border-box;
        border-radius: 0.375rem;
    }
}

.img__gold{
    width: 5rem;
}
    
    .comment-box {
        padding: 0.3125rem;
        margin-left: 2px;
    }
    
    .comment-area textarea {
        resize: none;
        border: 1px solid #ad9f9f
    }
    
    .form-control:focus {
        color: #495057;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-color:  #284876;
        outline: 0;
    }
    
    .btn-success {
     height: 2rem;
    }

    .send {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #ff0000;
        border-color: #ff0000
    }
    
    .send:hover {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #f50202;
        border-color: #f50202
    }
    
    .rating {
        display: flex;
        margin-top: -0.625rem;
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
        margin-left: -0.25rem;
        float: left
    }
    
    .rating>input {
        display: none
    }
    
    .rating>label {
        position: relative;
        width: 1.1875rem;
        font-size: 1.5625rem;
        color: #ff0000;
        cursor: pointer
    }
    
    .rating>label::before {
        content: "\2605";
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0
    }
    
    .rating>label:hover:before,
    .rating>label:hover~label:before {
        opacity: 1 !important
    }
    
    .rating>input:checked~label:before {
        opacity: 1
    }
    
    .rating:hover>input:checked~label:before {
        opacity: 0.4
    }

}

.btn{
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: transform 400ms; //pour indiquer au navigateur que la proprietés de transition est tranform
    &__hover:hover {
        transform: scale(1.15);
    }

    &--start:hover{
        transform: scale(1.05);
    }
}



@media screen and (max-width:900px){
    .carousel-inner > .carousel-item > img,
    .carousel-inner > .carousel-item > a > img {
        display: block;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: 18rem !important;
    } 
}

@media screen and (max-width:500px){
    .rate__box {

        .col-12 {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            background: #e04529;
            padding-top: 3rem;
            padding-bottom: 3rem;
            
            .card {
                position: relative;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                min-width: 0;
                padding: 1.25rem;
                width: 28.125rem;
                word-wrap: break-word;
                background-color: #fff;
                background-clip: border-box;
                border-radius: 0.375rem;
            }
        }
        
          
            
            .comment-box {
                padding: 0.3125rem;
                margin-left: 4px;
            }
            
            .comment-area textarea {
                resize: none;
                border: 1px solid #ad9f9f
            }
            
            .form-control:focus {
                color: #495057;
                background-color: #fff;
                border-color:  #284876;
                outline: 0;
            }
            
            .btn-success {
             height: 2rem;
            }
        
            .send {
                color: #fff;
                background-color: #ff0000;
                border-color: #ff0000
            }
            
            .send:hover {
                color: #fff;
                background-color: #f50202;
                border-color: #f50202
            }
            
            .rating {
                display: flex;
                margin-top: -0.625rem;
                flex-direction: row-reverse;
                margin-left: -0.25rem;
                float: left
            }
            
            .rating>input {
                display: none
            }
            
            .rating>label {
                position: relative;
                width: 1.1875rem;
                font-size: 1.5625rem;
                color: #ff0000;
                cursor: pointer
            }
            
            .rating>label::before {
                content: "\2605";
                position: absolute;
                opacity: 0
            }
            
            .rating>label:hover:before,
            .rating>label:hover~label:before {
                opacity: 1 !important
            }
            
            .rating>input:checked~label:before {
                opacity: 1
            }
            
            .rating:hover>input:checked~label:before {
                opacity: 0.4
            }

            .img__gold{
                width: 4.375rem;
            }
        
        }
}
```

full html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    
      <title>Info School</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="bg-dark">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <nav class="col navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
              <img src="logo.png" width="50" height="50" alt="Info Logo" />
              Info School
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div id="navbarContent" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
              <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item ">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Accueil</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="lessons.html">Cours</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="animations.html">Animations</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible fade show mt-3" role="alert">
                <h5 class="alert-heading">Prérequis</h5>
                <p>Bases en CSS. Si vous ne les maîtrisez pas, suivez ce cours : <a href="#" class="alert-link">Apprenez à créer votre site web avec HTML5 et CSS3</a> !</p>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
          <h1 class="my-3">Créez des animations CSS</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe
              class="embed-responsive-item"
              src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lOox4UJVFb4"
              frameborder="0"
              allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
              allowfullscreen>
            </iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row mt-3">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show mt-3 " role="alert">
                <h5 class="alert-heading pb-2">À la fin de ce cours, vous serez capable de :</h5>
                <ul>
                  <li>réaliser vos premières animations CSS</li>
                  <li>maîtriser les translations, les rotations et l’opacité</li>
                  <li>réaliser des animations dynamiques</li>
                </ul>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <hr>
          <h3>Notes</h3>
          <form>
            <div class="form-group mt-3">
              <label for="timeInput">Email :</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control form-control__text" id="timeInput" placeholder="email" aria-describedby="timeHelp">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mt-3">
              <label for="note">Note :</label>
              <textarea id="note" rows="5" class="form-control form-control__text--area" ></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox my-1 mr-sm-2">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input " id="customControlInline">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="customControlInline">Rendre cette notation publique</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn__hover btn--start btn-primary">Envoyer</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   <div class="container-fluid rate__box" >
<div class="row mt-3 mb-3">
  <div class="col col-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-3 img__gold "> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/xELPaag.jpg" width="80" class="rounded-circle mt-2"> </div>
          <div class="col-9">
              <div class="comment-box">
                  <h4>Add a comment</h4>
                  <div class="rating"> <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5" id="5"><label for="5">☆</label> <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4" id="4"><label for="4">☆</label> <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3" id="3"><label for="3">☆</label> <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" id="2"><label for="2">☆</label> <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" id="1"><label for="1">☆</label> </div>
                  <div class="comment-area"> <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="what is your view?" rows="4"></textarea> </div>
                  <div class="comment-btns mt-2 text-center">
               <button class="btn btn-success btn__hover send btn-sm">Send <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right ml-1"></i></button> 
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

 

   </div>
   
    <div class="bg-light mt-5">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row pt-4 pb-3">
          <div class="col">
            <ul class="list-inline text-center">
              <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">À propos</a></li>
              <li class="list-inline-item">&middot;</li>
              <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Vie privée</a></li>
              <li class="list-inline-item">&middot;</li>
              <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Conditions d'utilisations</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
  </body>
  </html>
```

My goal is to make this 100% responsive and to do it in the right way by the right layout and css properties

Comment: can u just tell how are you including scss in your html file

Comment: also attach full styles sheet for accurate answers because the comment section is not showing the way it's in the pic at my end

Comment: how to make the picture never touch the title and the text area in small screens?

Comment: om Nigam :   link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" after exectuting command sass --watch scss:css , the include is working fine , all the styles that i wrote are applied but the problem is that i did not handle the image in small screens , you can see that it became like a float , it should always look like in large screen but now it is almost like a float and that is why is posted to find a solution for this, my goal is to make it responsive and all elements especially the image keen distance from each other

Comment: can u provide me with full scss code for the comment section

Comment: .img__gold{
                width: 4.375rem;
            } here the style for image and the image is inside the same div .row of the title and text area and you can see that in the html part

Comment: https://codepen.io/OmN/pen/jOmBKwm check this out

Comment: i cannot see the correct thing

Comment: Have you tried viewport?

Comment: i saw the link but sorry it is not what i am looking for , what i am looking for is to keep the same view for my comment section but just when i open the view in small screen like Iphone SE for example , i want to see the image not floated on the other elements , that is all im searching for , i posted my full html and scss code

Comment: you can just move Add Comment text to new line and make the image block element

Comment: Garth Baker , this is not related to viewport , this is related just about how to make the image not floating on the other elements when i open it on small screens , i am not trying to change anything in cosmetics and styles , i just want my image to not float on anything on small screens , i want it to be the same like in large screen keeping a bit of distance from the other elements

Answer (score 1):

Specifically for your questions, I added the below to your html and it fixed your display, it is not the best implementation but I think you will get better with time ;) keep practicing and learn bootstrap. It's a great place to start :)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

You can play with the code here

```
https://codepen.io/Garth13/pen/oNWZyMr
```

1: Investigate media queries

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px){
    /*Tablets [601px -> 1200px]*/
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
    /*Big smartphones [426px -> 600px]*/
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 425px){
    /*Small smartphones [325px -> 425px]*/
}
```

2: Checkout viewport

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: if you look on my code you will see that i already used media queries

Comment: ok I am reading deeper and will help you out :)

Comment: have you used bootstrap before?

Comment: i just want to know what to change in scss or css and then i will copy what need to be changed in the small screens media query

Comment: ok I need to recreate in codepen give me 5 min

Comment: first time ,, i follow a tutorial and learned few little things

Comment: ok cool I highly recommend you checkout bootstrap in the future, it's really good for responsive web design, especially for beginners

Comment: will your answer be based on bootstrap ? i think it will be so cool

Comment: Sure I will add a bootstrap answer for you :) I am just going to use a CDN to link the style sheet for you

Comment: it is so hard to apply bootstrap on this comment section especially for beginners like me

Comment: So I kept all your code but I added bootstrap via a CDN and came up with that result

Comment: Also you might need to run this command ->     npm run dev

Comment: Bootstrap might be added but not compiled. Because when I added bootstrap via CDN your html changed

Comment: missing script run dev , this what i got after i run your command

Comment: Your bootstrap is not loading, if you add it via CDN does your stuff work?

Comment: You need to add this to your html head <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: it worked , for iphone 6/7/8 but for iphone SE and Iphone 5 the image is almost touching the text

Comment: Check the grid system link I added, the grid system in bootstrap will fix that :)

Comment: hard to apply with a complex view like this

Comment: i can see already that i implemented kind of grid layout but i think that i did not implement it correctly somewhere in my code

Comment: i already made the image inside a column col-3 and the other section on col-9